# "Error: could not find function" within function in R

Tags: r, function

I wrote a function:

```
funct1<-function(input1,input2,input3){
  ...
}
```

which uses another function, `funct2`, i.e. `funct2` is within `funct1`. Their codes are stored in two different files inside the same directory; respectively: `funct1.R` and `funct2.R`.

I've got the following error when launching `funct1`:

```
Error: could not find function "funct2"
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: `source("funct1.R")` and `source("funct2.R")`, or you could make a package..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure you load the script for funct2 before you try and use it in funct1. Like RLave has said in his comment use source("path_to/funct2.R"). You can put this within funct1 or at the top of your script for funct1.